# SQL File System Access - Job or Agent account?

Tags: sql

When running SQL server agent jobs that access the file system to write a file for example, which rights are used to authenticate?  The job owner or the agent account?

Answer (score 0):

The account that SQL agent is running under.  This account will need access to the filesystem. A safer way is to set up a proxy with the required privileges, and the job step can run as that proxy.

You can see how to set up a proxy here
 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064%28v=sql.105%29.aspx